# Apache Flume setup complexity

Tags: flume

There's many open-source messaging systems around, each with their own setup steps. 
This question is about Apache Flume, and about a very simple use case - moving data between two servers. What would be the amount of steps, and the amount of decisions to make in each step, for installing and configuring flume for just moving data between two servers?

Answer (score 0):

You need to download the binary zip for your OS, extract it and create a config file which is similar to  properties file in Java.

The installation and running of agents is an easy process, just read [Flume User Setup Guide](http://flume.apache.org/FlumeUserGuide.html#setup)